# Select from list of xml elements with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

Let's say I have this xml -

```
   <book>
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developers Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book>
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
   <book>
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
      <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
      society in England, the young survivors lay the 
      foundation for a new society.</description>
   </book>
```

I need a T-SQL query to select one book at a time from this list, because I need to do some kind of processing with that before I insert it into a table.

Let's say I want to select the second element in this list and want to display it as a table.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would shred the entire XML document into a table first, and if i REALLY couldn't do set based operations to them, iterate over the table using something like a row number and a loop, or a cursor.

If you just explicitly want to access the nth member of an xml document, you can do so when you write an xpath expression. How you'd know how many elements you need to iterate over though, I'm not sure. Here's an example of grabbing the 2nd book node:

```
--Assumes you've assigned the XML document you provided to an XML variable called @xml
select t.c.value('author[1]', 'varchar(50)')
from @xml.nodes('/book[2]') as t(c)
```